# Textbox on TextChanged event giving error!

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox in my webpage and I want to fire as soon User clicks or enter something on this textbox. Code is working but it is firing when an User hits Enter button. I want it to fire when user types their 1st character. Which event is app for this?

This is my mockup code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAgentName" runat="server" OnTextChanged = "txtAgentName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

But when I am running this webpage it is showing me this err:

```
CS0123: No overload for 'txtAgentName_TextChanged' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

I have this on my code behind:

```
  protected virtual void txtAgentName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Made a breakpoint in in here, and seems like it is firing when I am hitting Enter button. I want to fire when user enter 1st character inside that textbox.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the code for the txtAgentName_TextChanged function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblSearchResults.Text = "Search for: " + txtSearch.Text;
    }
</script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TextBox AutoPostBack</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <asp:Label
        id="lblSearch"
        Text="Search:"
        Runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox
        id="txtSearch"
        AutoPostBack="true"
        OnTextChanged="txtSearch_TextChanged"
        Runat="server" />

    <hr />

    <asp:Label
        id="lblSearchResults"
        Runat="server" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

your event handler must have this signature

```
protected void txtAgentName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```

does it?

Comment: @Mayank since you say the event is firing, I take it you don't have the error anymore?

Comment: Yes Bala. See this post. I was confused with the events in TBox. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733876/textbox-onclick-event-without-javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript's `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress", "GetKeyPress()")` and then postback if you wish.