# TextBox OnClick event without Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox which I want it to be fired on Click. I read some forum in which I wrapped in LinkButton. Here is my mockup UI part:

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat = "server" OnClick = "txtAgentName_TextChanged"><asp:TextBox ID="txtAgentName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></asp:LinkButton>
```

And this is my code behind:

```
  protected virtual void txtAgentName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

And it seems like it is not firing up! I dont want to use Javascript :-P

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "fired", if you need a change in the website without reloading, javascript is the only way.(As vbscript support has been dropped)

Comment: As soon as you say "onclick" you already are using javascript. Most ASP.NET server controls need javascript to support server side event triggering.

Comment: hhhmmm...so if I want to use JS. What do I need to do then?

Comment: Do you realize that you try to make post back on just click on the text box ?

Comment: Yes! I want to call my function which is in the code behind from JS. This is my question now!

Comment: Sounds like you might need to rethink this one. If you postback every time someone changes the value of the textbox, that is going to get really annoying really quickly. If you need something to happen each time some changes the value of a textbox, you should really be using JavaScript to handle everything associated with those changes... including whatever it is you are doing on the server-side.

What is your ultimate goal? What are you doing on the textbox change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the asp textbox control does not have a server side click event. "OnClick" renders an html "OnClick" attribute for the textbox. Your code will result in a javascript error.

your best bet is to do an ajax call to a WebMethod when the textbox blur event is fired and do something to the textbox based on the result. [this article](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) will help you with the webmethod call. using jquery you can handle the blur event pretty easily.